# After navigating to another page hybridWebView does not register any actions

Tags: xamarin.forms

I use project hybridWebView standart. [Xamarin.Forms - HybridWebView Custom Renderer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/xamarin-forms-samples/customrenderers-hybridwebview/)

1. If i use the html file that is in the Android project - Content / index.html - Everything works.
2. If I use html file which is hosted by mysite.com - The first time the hybridWebViewPage.axml page is loaded, I get the data in a variable `var data`. If I go to another page, and then go back to the hybridWebViewPage.axml page, I do not get data in the variable `var data`.
   `hybridWebView.RegisterAction(data => DisplayAlert("Alert", "Hello " + data, "OK"));`

Why is this happening?

Comment: You need to provide enough code in the body of your post to illustrate the problem you're having - this is a [mcve].  You should NOT expect us to download a sample project from another site, make a bunch of modifications, and then build it in order to understand what you're talking about.  This is asking us to do a lot of work in order to help you.

Comment: Sorry. I didn't want anyone to think so. I wanted people to be able to imagine steps to reproduce the problem. The first time the hybridWebViewPage.axml page is loaded, I get the data in a variable ```$data```.
If I go to another page, and then go back to the hybridWebViewPage.axml page, I do not get data in the variable ```data```.  I think if i post the code it doesn't help the case as i am not getting the error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the hybridWebView.RegisterAction method is called in the construction method of the contentpage which will be called when you navigate to it first time. In addition, when you come back from another page, the construction method will not be called because the instance of it is still in the storge. There is the link about the navigation stack.[link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/app-fundamentals/navigation/hierarchical)